# Issue about JComboBox with actionlistner

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

For the below example, I am writing a JComboBox with data 1,3,5,7,9, and expecting it will change to 2,4,6,8,10 after OK is pressed. However it just doesn't work.....  Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

Test (){
    final ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add(1);                                                           
    value.add(3);                                                          
    value.add(5);                   
    value.add(7);
    value.add(9);
    final JComboBox pulldown = new JComboBox(value.toArray());
    add(pulldown);

    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    add(ok);

    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int data [] = {2,4,6,8,10};                                       
         value.clear();
         for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
         {
         value.add(data[i]);  
         System.out.println(data[i]);
         }
        }
    });


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new Test();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: How does it not work? Please include the details required to answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the ArrayList data to set the JComboBox's **model** (here likely a DefaultComboBoxModel), but then later changing the ArrayList's data shouldn't and likely won't change the model once it's been set (although for other collections there may be risk of that happening).

Better to just go ahead and use a DefaultComboBoxModel to begin with.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>  model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
model.addElement(1);                                                           
model.addElement(3);                                                          
model.addElement(5);                   
model.addElement(7);
model.addElement(9);

final JComboBox pulldown = new JComboBox(model);
```

Then you can later change the model's data and be assured that the change will be reflected in the JComboBox's data display.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all old values from `JComboBox` you need to call method `myComboBox.removeAllItems()` and to add new items to it you need to call `myComboBox.addItem(myobject)`. Change this portion of your code,

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pulldown.removeAllItems();//removing all previous items
                int data[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
                value.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     pulldown.addItem(data[i]);//adding new items
                }
            }
        });
```